# How to use mongoose on angular2/browser

Tags: angular, mongoose, typescript-typings

I am new to MEAN and would like to seek your help.

Since I am using Mongoose on the server side and have a lot of schema, I would like to reuse the schema in the Angular2 browser side in my form input. As Mongoose is isomorphic now, I think it should be doable. If possible, I would like to use schema, document and validation on the client side with Mongoose/Angular2. I will not connect to a db from the browser.

Question1: how can I use the Mongoose on the broswer side?

I browsed around and am thinking this approach which may not correct.

1. npm install mongoose --save
2. typings install --global --save dt~mongoose (also mpromise, mongoose-promise, mongodb, node)
3. on app.module.ts, import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
4. copy those ....\typings\globals* to ....\node_modules (not sure I need this step, but just try it out)

When I did 'ng s', I got these error.

Question 2: how can I resolve these errors below? I also tried to npm install --save events, npm install --save stream and typings them.

ERROR in [default] D:\MEAN\projects\fhir\fhirapp\node_modules\mongodb\index.d.ts:4:29
**Cannot find module 'events'.**

ERROR in [default] D:\MEAN\projects\fhir\fhirapp\node_modules\mongodb\index.d.ts:102:18
Cannot find name 'Buffer'.

ERROR in [default] D:\MEAN\projects\fhir\fhirapp\node_modules\mongodb\index.d.ts:1127:44
Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

ERROR in [default] D:\MEAN\projects\fhir\fhirapp\node_modules\mongoose\index.d.ts:6:26
Cannot find module 'stream'.

ERROR in [default] D:\MEAN\projects\fhir\fhirapp\node_modules\mongoose\index.d.ts:13:29
Cannot find name 'global'.

My typings.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "mongodb": "registry:dt/mongodb#2.1.0+20160602142941",
    "mongoose": "registry:dt/mongoose#4.5.9+20160922172925",
    "mongoose-promise": "registry:dt/mongoose-promise#4.5.4+20160822161941",
    "mpromise": "registry:dt/mpromise#0.5.4+20160316155526",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160923124626"
  }
}
```

You help is high appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't need to copy anything from the `typings` folder to `node_modules`.

Comment: Hi WiredPrairie, thx for the confirmation. I was thinking to copy the correspodning index.d.ts to each node_modules/module_name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With TypeScript 2.0.3 installed (which if you're doing Angular 2.0+, you should be using), I used the following `package.json`:

```
npm install mongoose core-js --save
npm install @types/mongoose @types/core-js @types/node typescript --save-dev

{
  "name": "stackoverflow_mongoose",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/mongoose": "^4.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.41",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

I created an `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false
    }, 
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

And one sample file, `index.ts`:

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";

mongoose.connect("sample");
```

There are no compile errors. You shouldn't need to use `typings` anymore. Instead, you can use [`@types`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html).

Comment: Hi WiredPrairie, 

Thanks a lot!!!
After adding those suggested modules and @type, the issue was solved. However, I didn't npm the @type/core-js which caused a lot of error such as ERROR in [default] D:\...\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2015.core.d.ts:17:13
Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'. ERROR in [default] D:\..\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts:21:13 Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.

Comment: Dont know why you delete your question, if you give me the chance I would look for something else. I know the problem is because the unicode are sort differently. Try looking this article. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322112   . PD: I only  give the first duplicated, you know I can only give one. But the second have some interesting comment may help you too.

Comment: Well even when mark as duplicated you can ask for reopen by editing your question and explaining why is different. I will change my vote after reading your comment. Again sorry for the inconvenient.